# Vimeo Iframe Error "Sorry we're having little trouble" in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, iframe, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

There are sequences of videos that will play one after another. This issue occurs randomly. When the page reloads it is working fine. Earlier it worked well. can anyone help me to solve this?

[image]